# Finding root changeset of tip for pull, graft, strip workflow in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

If I have a repo that looks like this:

```
A--B--C--D
    \
     E--F--G
```

How can I specify revision E? I can do something like -r 'ancestors(D,G)' to get B, but I want a reasonable way to specify E.

Also, let me explain why I'm doing this in case there is a better workflow.

In the above picture, A--B--C is in a main repository. A--B--E--F--G is in my own private forked repository, and I need to merge F (and only F) into the main repo. To do this, I pull my private repo into main, then graft F (to create D), and then use the hg strip extension to remove E--F--G and then push back up to the main repo.

Currently I do this by opening a gui tool and looking at the picture of the branches and manually copy-pasting the revision E from that tool. I don't like to use GUI tools to actually manage the repo, so I just paste that revision into a terminal for hg strip. This is the only thing I still need to do in the gui tool and I'd rather not have to launch it each time I do this. What I want, is to figure out how to specify the revision and then make an alais that does hg strip on that revision

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that `min(descendants(max(ancestor(D,G))) and not ancestors(D))` will get what you want.

It finds the newest common ancestor of D and G (`max(ancestor(D,G))`), gets all of its descendants and then excludes the ancestors of D.  Finally, it uses `min()` to get the oldest of that set which is E.

The `max()` isn't really required in your example but covers the chance that you could have merged the main branch into yours at some point.  You could remove that to make the query shorter.  You could also shorten it by using `::` as a shortcut for `ancestors()` and `descendants()` and `!` as a shortcut for `not` which gives a crazy looking `min(ancestor(D,G)::) and !::D)`

I really wouldn't just pass this revset to `hg strip` though.  I'd make sure that it gives the revision that you want before stripping it.

I'd consider using the [Mercurial Queues](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension) extension for this workflow.  You'd basically keep E, F and G in a patch queue, unapply all of them, pull, update to C, apply F and discard E and G.  This would be something like this:

```
> hg qpop all
> hg pull -u
> hg qpush --move F
> hg qdelete E
> hg qdelete G
```

Where F, E and G are the names of the patch files that you created using `hg qnew`.  It seems like a nicer workflow to me and doesn't involve deleting commits using complicated revset queries.

Comment: Thanks! I came up with something kind of similar, but instead of specifying D and G manually, I wanted to use `head() and tag("tip")` or something like that to avoid copy-pasting the revision and the thing just got way too unwieldy. I'll look into queues

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a better solution to my workflow, since I'm working with remote repositories.

I have a `remote1` that containts `A--B--C` and a `remote2` that has `A--B--E--F--G` and I want to graft `F` onto `remote1`.

Here'es the workflow I came up with, starting in a local clone of `remote1` (using `outgoing` to solve the root problem)

```
$ hg pull remote2
$ hg graft F
$ hg push -r tip
$ hg strip -r 'roots(outgoing())'
```